# How to implement custom routing in Akka.Net

Tags: c#, akka.net

Akka.Net provides a number of usefull routing strategies out of the box (we currently use smallest mailbox and consistent hashing), but what if want to implement custom router with strategy based on let's call it Worker Node Load Index which is will be calculated separetly on each node based on current resource consumption.

I could not find docs or examples regarding this topic, so any info is higly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own routing strategy by deriving from the base `RoutingLogic` class: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/614f1f0e824384f065e7b72e827c1ff937eafca5/src/core/Akka/Routing/Router.cs#L166

Overall your class might look a bit like:

```
public class CustomRouter : RoutingLogic
{
    public override Routee Select(object message, Routee[] routees)
    {
        return routees.OrderBy(WorkerNodeLoadIndex).First();
    }

    private double WorkerNodeLoadIndex(Routee arg)
    {
        return 0.0; // put your real calculation here
    }
}
```