# How to implement custom routing with dynamic router routees in Akka.Net

Tags: c#, akka.net

Very similar question to: [How to implement custom routing in Akka.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654665/how-to-implement-custom-routing-in-akka-net)

I want to use a router for a cache framework, that have a rolling window time frame. I want the router to route the message to the correct actor base on values (combination) in the message. I cant use the consistent hashing router because the list can grow and the count is not known before hand.

I can implement a IDictionary and have a parent actor that creates a new actor when the key isnt found. It feels dirty and i think i will have supervisor strategy problems and need to implement some kind of health checks.

Isnt there a way I can create a custom router, similar to the answer to the above question?

Note: the actor that holds the state needs to do real time aggregation and calculations on event.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it sounds like [Akka.Cluster.Sharding](https://petabridge.com/blog/introduction-to-cluster-sharding-akkadotnet/) is more what you're looking for. It allows you to route messages to actors in the cluster (and to create them ad-hoc, if they don't exist yet). It also covers scenarios like rebalancing and migration of actors from dead nodes (so maybe you won't need any health checks).